# Spring Data Rest @RepositoryRestResource and Jackson @JsonView

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest, jackson-databind

Is it possible to combine Jackson `@JsonView()` and Spring Data Rest `@RepositoryRestResource` in order to have a repository method return (or accept) a view of an object?

I.e. is it possible to write something like this (which of course I tried but with no success)?

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    @JsonView({UserView.ReadOnly.class})
    Optional<User> findById(Long id);

    <S extends User> S save(@JsonView({UserView.Updatable.class}) S s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read about projections, which will solve your problem.

Here is an example
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-projections-excerpts

Comment: I already know about projections and excerpts but they do not solve my problem. Unfortunately they are not applied by default when operating on a single resource and neither they are when deserializing an object.

Comment: But you can return a list of ProjectedUser for exampke